# Importing GitHub project to AndroidStudio not appearing correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, github, repository

I'm working on an Android application and I've pushed it to GitHub from my windows computer, I'm having problems to pull the code from repository in Mac OS, when it downloads it shows like if the project was corrupt or something.

It shows this:

[image: Android-studio project]

As you can see the project doesn't download the folder app and all the files that i pushed to the [Repository](https://goo.gl/EcFjBr)

I might not be pushing it correctly because i've tried to clone well built Android repositories and and they work nicely.

Thanks a lot for your help and Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things which you need to do, crate a directory where you want the project to be set up this.

I made a directory called `Juanjors_AndroidMeneame` and navigated my git bash there.

[image]

as shown in the image initialize local git repository.

and then pull the data.  as shown in the image

```
git pull https://github.com/Juanjors/AndroidMeneame.git
```

after this import the project, and this is what you will get

[image]

Comment: I might be stupid but I'm not able to to import it correctly. In the folder i can see all the files but in AndroidStudio i can't see them and the execute button is disabled.  

[Here you can see what i did](http://i.imgur.com/ObBHWac.jpg)

Thanks alot!

Comment: @NoOne, when you import in android studio, you don't have to go inside the directory where you saved the code, just click on the directory and click on import